[SpringCloudGateway-WebFlux]: How to return custom error response for Gateway timing out lingering downstream endpoint?
We have implemented our Gateway application using Spring Cloud Gateway 4.1.0 framework and it is able to intercept the incoming request and redirect to configured downstream endpoint.
We have configured following timeout settings in order to cater lingering downstream endpoints which takes longer time to process the redirected requests from Gateway application:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 15000
        response-timeout: 15000

Due to above timeout configuration, Gateway app is now able to timeout the redirected request processing by downstream endpoints that is taking more than 15 sec to process the request and returning 504 Gateway Timeout response.
However, we are observing unexpected behavior that after timeout of the redirected request, Gateway app does not execute any custom global post-filters from the filter chain. It just executes the custom pre-filters and routes requests to downstream endpoint and then terminate the request after timeout.
We have requirement to format error response in JSON format and return to the client for further processing in this scenario. We have implemented custom global post filter to format the error response, however the post filters are not executed so only 504 response status code is only returned.
The routing of request to downstream endpoint is performed by NettyRoutingFilter framework class which does not provide any callback for timing out the lingering endpoint processing, so no way to handle it there also.
Any help to resolve the issue is highly appreciated.

You might e able to extend netty routing filter, define it as a bean and override a method
